# Achievements view title bar clickable, and obscured view is affected

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

[image]

When the achievements button is clicked, the overlay view title bar is still clickable and propagates the click event through to the view underneath, e.g. the question type selector shown in the screenshot above.

App version: 1.0.47

Comment: Yup. It's a duplicate of it. I've searched through the questions about this issue but found nothing. That question tittle should get changed to any other more clear about the problem.

Comment: That's a nice one. Will keep an eye on yours.